# Failed with exit code 1 Error In cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova

```
C:\phoneGap\firstApp>cordova run android

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\sdk\
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74 Unzipping C:\Users\Somnath Sarkar\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.13-all\7hsc6vr6mi3i6i5m7q9hj4ci1q\gradle-2.13-all.zip to C:\Users\Somnath Sarkar\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.13-all\7hsc6vr6mi3i6i5m7q9hj4ci1qException in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file 
     at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
     at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
     at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)      
     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)      
     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)
     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)      
     at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65) ... 3 more    
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file      
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)      
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)      
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)      
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48) 
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file      
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)      
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)      
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)      
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)      
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)      
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)      
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)      
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)      
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65) ... 3 more
```

Comment: Please Give me a proper solution

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) Please format your input, show the program code and add a reasonable question to  your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Delete "gradle-2.13-all.zip" folder and everything in this directory:

> C:\Users\Somnath
>   Sarkar.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.13all\7hsc6vr6mi3i6i5m7q9hj4ci1q\

2. Download the gradle zip manually [click here](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip)
3. Paste the gradle zip folder in

> C:\Users\Somnath
>   Sarkar.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.13-all\7hsc6vr6mi3i6i5m7q9hj4ci1q\

4. Run your

> Codova build android

Comment: For new visitors, this solution is still valid, just change the gradle version accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file** which means the concurrent **ZIP file was Corrupted**.

**Solution :**

Please Check the Zip file in `C:\Users\YourUsername\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.13-all\someRandomSting\` size and if it'size not equals to 66.6M then Download and Replace with [this](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip)

Comment: For future visitors: if your Gradle version is different, you can view the full list and download the appropriate file here: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/