# java.util.zip.zipException while building NativeScript project

Tags: java, android, nativescript, gradlew

I am getting a `java.util.zip.ZipException` while preparing my NativeScript project for Android (`tns prepare android`):

```
Failed to build plugin nativescript-barcodescanner : 
Error: Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1 Error output: 
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
```

This error seems to be occurring only when certain plugins (`nativescript-barcodescanner` and `nativescript-socket.io`) are installed. If I try to build without those plugins, the build works properly. So it's probably not a problem with Gradle itself (as in e.g.[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42967664/1196444)).

## First occurrence

I first encountered the problem with `nativescript-barcodescanner` after upgrading NativeScript from version `3.2.0` to `4.2.4` and subsequently updating my project packages as well. Everything was working fine before the upgrade.

However, the problem is not specific to my project. If I create a new project and add `nativescript-barcodescanner`

```
$ tns create testproject && cd testproject
$ tns plugin add nativescript-barcodescanner
$ tns prepare android
```

...then the error shows up again. When I `tns remove nativescript-barcodescanner`, the build runs properly.

## Steps taken

At first, I thought it was a problem with the `nativescript-barcodescanner` plugin ([here is my GitHub issue](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-barcodescanner/issues/166)). However, I now ran into the same error with a NativeScript-Vue template, where the build failed at `nativescript-socket.io`.

I have tried the following steps, without success:

- Deleting `node_modules` and re-running `npm install`
- Clearing the npm cache (`~/.npm/_cacache`) and re-downloading all dependencies
- Creating a fresh NativeScript project (problem comes back when I `tns add` the plugin)
- Removing the plugin and installing an older version
- Re-installing NativeScript (`npm i -g nativescript`)
- Deleting the Gradle cache folder (`~/.gradle/caches`) and retrying the build
- Using a newer version of java (OpenJDK 11 instead of 8)

My (current) guess is that some file that has been incorrectly downloaded. This is quite likely because my Internet connection is not very great and might have disconnected in the middle. However, I can't make out *which* file is causing trouble (I'd rather not re-download the whole setup).

## Full output

Here is my NativeScript setup info:

```
$ tns info
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 4.2.4 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-core-modules has 4.2.1 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-android has 4.2.0 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-ios has 4.2.0 version and is up to date.
```

And this is a sample run (this was with OpenJDK 8 so it says `error opening zip file` instead of the more detailed `zip END header not found`):

```
$ tns create bartest
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
added 3 packages in 295.509s
Project bartest was successfully created.

$ cd bartest
$ tns plugin add nativescript-barcodescanner
+ nativescript-barcodescanner@2.7.8
added 1 package in 97.781s
Successfully installed plugin nativescript-barcodescanner.

$ tns prepare android
Copying template files...
Platform android successfully added. v4.2.0
Preparing project...
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-barcodescanner for android.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-theme-core for android.
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules for android.
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules-widgets for android.
Failed to build plugin nativescript-barcodescanner : 
Error: Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1 Error output: 
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:215)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:75)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
  at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

Is there any way to figure out which zip file is causing the error, or other way I can try to debug this problem?

Comment: Try adding `--stacktrace` or `--debug` to gradle, either by editing the wrapper script or the [build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29977196/how-can-i-make-gradle-stacktrace-the-default)

Comment: Thanks. NativeScript seems to be re-generating `build.gradle` and associated files every time the command is run. I'm trying to figure out how to override it, will get back when I do :-/

Comment: The link I provided also has an `~/.gradle/init.gradle` that you can use to override all gradle on the system.

Comment: That's not working either; I don't know why. Maybe I need to manipulate some of the environment variables to get it to look in the right place?

Comment: When you removed the `node_modules`, did you also remove `platforms`?  https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+ZipException

Comment: try tns platform remove android after tns plugin add nativescript-barcodescanner

Comment: None of the combinations worked. However, I realised I have a bad `.zip` file in my `~/.gradle`. Perhaps NativeScript is using a different gradle to build the plugins (`gradle-4.4-bin` instead of `gradle-4.4-all`), which would explain why plugin builds fail when ordinary builds don't—and why adding `--stacktrace` didn't work.

Comment: Yes—replacing the faulty gradle file worked! @JamesPoag that also explains why I couldn't enable `--stacktrace`: because it never reached that stage. Lesson learnt: always double-check gradle, even if it seems to work sometimes. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** One of the zip files in my `~/.gradle` was faulty. Re-downloading the file solved the problem.

My error in reasoning was this:

> This error seems to be occurring only when certain plugins
>   (nativescript-barcodescanner and nativescript-socket.io) are
>   installed. If I try to build without those plugins, the build works
>   properly. So it's probably not a problem with Gradle itself (as in
>   e.g.[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42967664/1196444)).

The fact that some builds work **does not necessarily imply** that Gradle is set up properly. NativeScript seems to use different versions for different tasks (in my case, `gradle-4.4-bin` for plugin builds but `gradle-4.4-all` for full-project builds). If only the project-build version is faulty, builds will work for some setups but fail when a plugin build is also required.

## Solutions

**Quick solution:** Delete the `~/.gradle` folder and run the build command again (as described in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3930)).

**Slower solution:** To avoid re-downloading the whole setup, look through the `gradle-*.zip` files, located in `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists`, and find out which one is faulty (which probably means it wasn't downloaded properly). The files will be named something like (as in my case) this:

```
~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.4-bin/bgaq7vklkazwgxox0hdadxbvi/gradle-4.4-bin.zip
```

To check for faulty zips, compare the filesize and/or sha-sum to [this Gradle Distribution List](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/). **Simply opening the `.zip` is not sufficient testing**, because many file managers open partially-downloaded/incomplete zipfiles without complaining.

Once you find the faulty file, delete it and re-run the `tns build` command. It will automatically download the missing file and continue with the build. Alternatively, you can manually download the file from the above link and place it in the correct directory.

Comment: Don't delete the whole folder as you might have important stuff in here (like publish keys/passwords).

Answer (score 1):

1. go to the .gradle folder
2. find the latest Gradle version if have
   and
3. after open the VS code and in file explore project-> Android->gradle/wrapper->gradle-wrapper.properties

paste distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip

7.0.2 <- this change with the version (enter the latest gradle version)

and Run the project !!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the problem and noticed that the downloaded `gradle-x.x.x.x.zip` size differs from the real size (`gradle-7.3.3-bin` size was 110 MB but the downloaded one was 101 MB). Therefore, I decided to download it manually and change `distributionUrl` to the local file

*gradle-wrapper.properties*

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
```

I downloaded `gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip` and inserted it to:

```
%PROJECT_DIR%\platforms\android\gradle\wrapper
```

And the error gone !